# How to send form data along with dropzone files through ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, json, dropzone.js

I am new in jquery and dropzone.

I have a issue related to dropzone.js. I have to send the form data (like custome_name, id, DOB etc.) along with image files dropped in dropzone.

How can I send my data string along with dropzone files on single click button event using AJAX to the PHP script?

Thanks in advance. Your little support will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [tips](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#tips) section of the Dropzone.js documentation,

> Dropzone will submit any hidden fields you have in your dropzone form

So that might be an option for you. Alternatively, you can also specify extra data with the `params` option which might look something like:

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
  paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
  maxFilesize: 2, // MB
  params: {
    customer_name: 'Jeffrey Lebowski',
    dob: '1949-11-20',
    ...
  },
  ...
};
```

It is not documented very well so I'm only *guessing* how the `Dropzone.options` approach would work.

Comment: thanks for suggestion but this is same for me, where I stuck with this problem i don't know what is the mean of "Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone".

Comment: Can you update your question with how you're initializing the Dropzone? Then maybe I can update my answer with something that fits your use case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm coming late but if there is someone with the same problem, I solved it quite differently.

I only use dropzone for the UX for the user, and give the drag and drop function to my site, but I wanted to submit all the information at once in a single button.

First I initialize my dropzone area, in my case I used a div, not a form to contain the dropzone.

```
 $animalImage = new Dropzone('div#animalImage', {
        // url: '/file/post',
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        //thumbnailWidth: "100",
        //thumbnailHeight: "100",
        uploadMultiple: true,
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        parallelUploads: 4,
        maxFilesize: 4,
        maxFiles: 4,
        maxfilesexceeded: function (files) {
            this.removeAllFiles();
            this.addFile(files);
        },
        acceptedFiles: '.png,.jpg,.jpeg',
        dictDefaultMessage: '<span class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-cloud-upload text-info" style="margin-right:5px"></i>' + 
            'Arrastra una imagen <span class="font-xs">para guardar</span></span><span>&nbsp&nbsp' + '<h4 class="display-inline"> (O Click Aquí)</h4></span>',
        //dictResponseError: 'Error al subir imagen',
        dictRemoveFile: '<i class="fa fa-times-circle" style="font-weight: 900; cursor:pointer;"></i>' 
    });
```

Then I declared and array (this is the way I expect to recieve it in my controller and model) extracted all the files in my save function, dropzone allow you to access its compiled data for each image, and added it to my array images.

```
images = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < $animalImage.files.length; i++) {
            images.push($animalImage.files[i]);
        }
```

Last I added it to my json object.

```
animal.Pictures = images;
```

At the end in my model I recived all my info contained my form and the dropzone array of images as I was expecting.

Hope it helps.